# validate and capture selected button-group checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap button-group checkbox with toggle. To easily identify selected option, using the toggle function (courtesy - one of the post here). Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEX9g/).

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="Test">Boxes</label>
<div class="controls" name="Test"> 
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
<div class="btn btn-default" class-toggle="btn-info">AA</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" class-toggle="btn-info">BB</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" class-toggle="btn-info">CC</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

stumped with:

1) how to validate that user has to select at least 1 button and
2) how to capture value(s) of selected buttons to be sent to PHP (form).

very novice with web development. Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have three buttons as shown below:

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Button1">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Button2">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Button3">
```

You can make a hidden field there with an array as given below:

```
<input type="hidden" class="newField" name="buttonValue[]">
```

Now, use it in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var values = $(this).val();
        $('.hidden').val(values);
    });
});
```

and now when you submit a form then you can easily get value from that field and make a validation accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

there is many ways to do this if you want to submit a form with PHP than its very simple you can add a class and use a hidden fields on the click you can add a class and put a value on hidden field and after the submit you can easily get all the value form hidden fields. you can easily check value of hidden fields, so with this you can validate as well that user select any button or not..

Comment: i am an accountant by profession. just getting hang of web technologies. is it possible to guide with an example? or am i asking too much. really don't know how this forum works.